# MITMProxy: Generated cert and downloaded cert are not the same

Tags: ssl-certificate, mitmproxy

After running `mitmproxy` for the first time, the cert generated in `~/.mitmproxy` is not the same as those available on http://mitm.it Shouldn't the certs be the same on both the server and the client?

Comment: @Robert Sorry, that was a typo as I was on my phone. I noticed the serial number of the ones on http://mitm.it is `0E:EC:B0:E8:77:C1` but the serial number of the ones in `~/.mitmproxy` is `0E:EC:C4:E3:74:93`.

Comment: The certs are the same if you have mitm running on the system and user account  you are checking the `~/.mitmproxy` path. An easier comparison is the issue date they contain. May be your set-up is non-standard and you have started multiple instances of mitm? The issue date should give you an indicator when the mitm instance was first started. If that does not help please edit your question and describe your complete mitm set-up.